# How to do Auto redirect to .min Files

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need a redirect from /js/qwerty.js to /js/qwerty.min.js if min.js exists.
My config:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # if a min version is available then load it
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.min.$2 -f
    RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.(css|js)$ /$1.min.$2 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't work :(

Comment: might be a conflict between the condition and the rule?

Comment: What do you mean? I have only one condition...

Comment: I mean, you redirect css/js files but they might not exists in the document_root.  just a thought...  just to make sure, disable the condition and test...

Comment: No, I have both of files: http://localhost/style.css and http://localhost/style.min.css
But if I call http://localhost/style.css I see uncomressed content :(